# Multiple apache2 Virtual host sitses - All work except one

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I have a problem with apache2 and Virtual Hosts. I run a server with multiple sites. I have subdomains setup that point to my server IP. My customers, those that choose to have their own domain names point their domain/sub-domain to one of my subdomains. I've done this with multiple sites and it's always worked, except for now, and I cant figure out why.
This is the virtual host that doesnt seem to work, it always points to my default site when i try to access it.

The domain redirecting goes like this. customer.domain.com -> customer.mydomain.com -> server IP

```
<VirtualHost customer.domain.com:443>
    ServerName customer.domain.com
    ServerAlias *customer.domain.com *customer.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/page

  <Directory />
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
  </Directory>

  <Directory /var/www/page>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/customer/logs/error.log

  LogLevel warn

  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/customer/logs/access.log combined

  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key


  BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" \
    nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
    downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
</VirtualHost>
```

This format is used for all other sites, and they are directed to the correct folder and site. But with this particular site it always gets directed to the default site.

I've noticed that when i run apache2ctl -S I get two IPs. One is my servers IP with all of the virtual hosts, and the second IP seems connected to the new virtual host, the one that doesnt work.

```
52.52.52.52:443       customer.domain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/006-customer.domain.com.conf:1)
12.12.12.12:443       is a NameVirtualHost
         default server default.mydomain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/001-default.mydomain.com.conf:1)
         port 443 namevhost default.mydomain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/001-default.mydomain.com.conf:1)
                 alias www.default.mydomain.com
         port 443 namevhost customer2.domain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/002-customer2.domain.com.conf:1)
                 alias www.customer2.domain.com
                 wild alias *subdomain.mydomain.com
*:80                   default.mydomain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1) ..... more
```

I'm not really sure what to look for, the logs don't seem to tell me anything useful.

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: UPDATE: I've noticed that when i try to access the site via "https://"customer.domain.com I get ERR_CONNECTION_RESET, this website is not available. Without https I go straight to default site.

Comment: Probably due to a bad Listen directive or no virtualhost *:443?

Comment: @covener Can you please elaborate. Thank you.

Comment: You should make sure you're listening on all interfaces on port 443 and not specific ones (by checking your config for Listen) You should also make a sure an SSL-enabled vhost exists that matches all interfaces (*:443) rather than particular ones. You'll get this for free if you consider my answer below that puts you in a typical configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid putting hostnames inside of <virtualhost> at all costs.  On a typical system, *:port in each vhost is sufficient.

If you really care about what local interface a connection is related to BEFORE checking the hostname used, put a local interface address name and not a hostname.  But most people simply do not care what interface was used.

The particular risk of using a hostname is that it might not resolve to any local interface, in which case Apache will never map a connection to it.    The per-request hostname matching only kicks in from the best matching connection-level info.